# How can I change the type of the tree to return the correct value for almost any kind of tree?

Tags: ocaml

I'm trying to find the maximum value of nodes tree and I have this kind of error
This expression has type `int bintree` but an expression was expected of type `'a bintree bintree`.
Type `int` is not compatible with type `'a bintree`.

```ml
type 'a bintree =
| Nil
| T of 'a bintree * 'a * 'a bintree ;;

let t = T (T (T (Nil, 1, Nil), 2, T (Nil, 3, Nil)), 4, T (T (Nil, 6, Nil), 5, Nil)) ;;

let rec maximum t = 
  match t with
  |Nil -> Nil
  | T (Nil, v, Nil) -> v
  | T (l, v, r) -> max (maximum l) (maximum r) ;;
```

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is in determining the maximum of an empty tree. The maximum should be of type `'a` but you are returning `Nil`, which is of type `'a bintree`.

This is actually an interesting problem. You need a value that works for any type. But there's really no such value.

One possibility would be to have an extra argument that specifies the value to use when the tree is empty. It would represent negative infinity (the smallest possible value) for whatever type is in the tree.

Another (probably better) solution, as suggested by @ThéoWinterhalter, is to have your function return type `'a option`. It would return `None` when the tree is empty, and `Some maxval` otherwise.

Comment: Wouldn't the proper way be to use `option`? With `maximum Nil = None`.

Comment: Yes, I was just about to add this to my answer. Thanks!

Comment: Doesn't your last branch need to consider v too?

Comment: Could you neglect the left branch if you have a right branch with a value? Sorry, I was thinking of a sorted tree.

Comment: This is a common problem when trying to define "maximum" or "minimum" functions over various containers. Another way besides those already mentioned is to ensure that the container has at least one element. 1. Extract one value from the tree or call `invalid_arg "empty tree"` 2. Use that value as the initial best candidate so you don't have to deal with an option type.

Answer (score 0):

This is a common problem when scanning a collection of items for an optimum element of some kind, such as a maximum or a minimum value. The issue is that the container may be empty, in which case it's not possible to extract a "best element". OCaml provides the `option` type for expressing a value or the absence of a value so it's a good idea to use it here. This is what my solution would look like:

```
let maximum t =
  let rec loop best t =
    match t with
    | Nil -> best
    | T (l, v, r) ->
      let best = max best v in
      let best = max best (loop best l) in
      loop best r
  in
  match t with
  | Nil -> None
  | T (_, init, _) -> Some (loop init t)
```

This returns `None` if the tree is empty i.e. if it is `Nil`. Otherwise it returns `Some v` where `v` is the best element of the collection, i.e. the maximum as determined by the `max` function.

This technique relies on first extracting one element from the container. This is our initial candidate. Then we proceed by scanning the container for better candidates, and finally returning the best candidate we've found. The same technique can be adapted to work on lists, arrays and other containers. It can also be parametrized so as to take a "best-of-two" function as argument, such as `min` if we wanted to obtain the minimum instead of the maximum.